# How to create multiple selectable paragraphs in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a document viewer, I want my users to be able to select the whole article and copy the text. Ideally when there are images or videos in the document, they can still select everything but only copy the text content, basically like a webpage.

I tried `SelectableText`, it creates one line of selectable text, but I can't select multiple `SelectableText` widgets at once.

With `SelectableText.rich()` I can put multiple `TextSpan` in one widget, but I can't find a way to add line wraps, all texts appear as one line. Besides it doesn't allow anything else other than `TextSpan`, no `WidgetSpan` so no image/video.

Doesn't Flutter support this seemly basic use case?

Answer (score 1):

[Flutter 3.3](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-3-893c7b9af1ff) introduced the [`SelectableArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea-class.html) widget which enables selection for any of its children.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: SelectionArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text('Row 1'),
                Text('Row 2'),
                Text('Row 3'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this part of code, i don't know what exactly you're trying to do so it is better if you explain or show some more, but from what I understand you need something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Selectable extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ToolBar"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      body: ListView(

        children: <Widget>[
          Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              SelectableText("""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""")
            ],
          ),

          Container(child: Image.asset('assets/images/search.jpg')),
          Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              SelectableText("""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""")
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Attend to the Wrap widget and the triple quotes """ long text  """

feel free to communicate...

Comment: the answer is eddited

Comment: You can't select text in both `SelectableText`s at once, you can only select text in one of them. I'm looking for a solution to **select all** text in the document.